# pandas: select rows - based on list - DF with duplicate rows labels

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, filter, dataframe

similar to this but not the same: [Selecting rows - based on a list - from a DF with duplicated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425232/selecting-rows-based-on-a-list-from-a-df-with-duplicated-columns)

I have two dfs:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'total': [25, 45, 75, 36, 45]}, 
                   index=['base', 'c', 'd', 'base', 'e'])
      total
base     25
c        45
d        75
base     36
e        45

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['rc', 'rc', 'c%', 'c%', 'pp%']}, 
                    index=['base', 'c', 'd', 'base', 'e'])

     type
base   rc
c      rc
d      c%
base   c%
e      pp%
```

I want to get the rows where values is 'c%' and/or 'pp%' within df2 from df1.

here is how I'm doing it

```
keep = df2[df2['type'].isin(['c%', 'pp%'])].index
Index([u'd', u'base', u'e'], dtype='object')

df1.loc[keep]
      total
d        75
base     25
base     36
e        45
```

'base    25' shouldn't be there but because I'm using labels I understand why it's there.

desired outcome:

```
      total
d        75
base     36
e        45
```

How can I change my code to handle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [9]:

(df2['type'] == 'c%') | (df2['type'] == 'pp%')
Out[9]:
base    False
c       False
d        True
base     True
e        True
Name: type, dtype: bool

In [8]:
df1[(df2['type'] == 'c%') | (df2['type'] == 'pp%')]
Out[8]:
     total
d      75
base   36
e      45
```

Comment: What about resetting the index? as the filtering may not be based on a Boolean.

Comment: do you want to slice based on `true` or `false` values or based on `indices`  ?

Comment: indices. apologies the true and false was just an example and easier to explain.

Comment: you mentioned `I want to get the rows which are 'True' from df2 from df1` , actually I couldn't understand your question

Comment: I've updated my question, hope it's a bit clearer. Using true and false was not a good idea.

Comment: looks like this is what I want: df1.loc[df2['type'].isin(['c%', 'pp%'])]

Comment: yeah if I understand you well your answer should work , I edited also my answer , another way to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to get?

```
In [54]: df1[['total']][df2['bool']=='True']
Out[54]: 
      total
d        75
base     36
e        45
```